# Creating oposite Mirror picture by manipulate Kinect Color pixels

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to create an opposite mirror picture from the color stream, i.e., when right hand is moving up, I want that kinect will draw the left had to move up (unlike in-front of real mirror that the right hand is raising )i want to manipulate the color image to do that: just moving the X position. However, I get a blue screen :

```
    void kinectSensor_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
               using (ColorImageFrame colorImageFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
            {
                if (colorImageFrame != null)
                {
                    byte[] pixelsFromFrame = new byte[colorImageFrame.PixelDataLength];
                     colorImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(pixelsFromFrame);
                     Color[] color = new Color[colorImageFrame.Height * colorImageFrame.Width];
                    kinectRGBVideo = new Texture2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, colorImageFrame.Width, colorImageFrame.Height);

                    // Go through each pixel and set the bytes correctly
                    // Remember, each pixel got a Rad, Green and Blue
                    int index = 0;
                    for (int y = 0; y < colorImageFrame.Height; y++)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < colorImageFrame.Width; x++, index += 4)
                        {
                            color[(y * colorImageFrame.Width + x)] = new Color(pixelsFromFrame[(y+1)*(2560 -index)],
                                pixelsFromFrame[(y + 1) * (2560 - index)],
                                pixelsFromFrame[(y + 1) * (2560 - index)]);
                         }
                    }
                               // Set pixeldata from the ColorImageFrame to a Texture2D
                   kinectRGBVideo.SetData(color);


                }
            }
        }
        catch { 


        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is worng ?
Thanks
erez

Answer (score 0):

The code to create a reflection is

```
unsafe void reflectImage(byte[] colorData, int width, int height)
{
    fixed (byte* imageBase = colorData)
    {
        // Get the base position as an integer pointer
        int* imagePosition = (int*)imageBase;
        // repeat for each row
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            // read from the left edge
            int* fromPos = imagePosition + (row * width);
            // write to the right edge
            int* toPos = fromPos + width - 1;
            while (fromPos < toPos)
            {
                *toPos = *fromPos;
                 //copy the pixel
                 fromPos++; // move towards the middle
                 toPos--; // move back from the right edge
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This makes it so that the bytes in `toPos` and `fromPos` switch sides because the code fixes a byte pointer at the base of the image data bytes and then creates an integer pointer from that value. This means that to copy all the data bytes for a single pixel from one place to another, the program can use a single statement: `*toPos = *fromPos;`

[Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735663963)

Comment: this doesn't swap bytes, the value of toPos is now lost when it is overwritten by fromPos. To properly swap values, you should add a temporary buffer integer outside the loops, and in the loops copy toPos value to the buffer, then assign fromPos to toPos, and finally assign the temporary to fromPos.